# Magento 2 API add item to Cart ignore price

Tags: magento2, api, price

if i add a item to cart via api it set Magento 2 default price of the item instead price set via API

1st i create a cart for a customer:

> index.php/rest/default/V1/customers/631/carts

via POST

> index.php/rest/default/V1/carts/{cartid}/items

via POST

json:

> { "cartItem": { "quote_id": "cart_id_from_1st_response", "sku":
>   "test_sku", "qty": 1, "price": "11" } }

the response is like that:

> ```
> stdClass Object
>     (
>         [item_id] => 186
>         [sku] => test_sku
>         [qty] => 1
>         [name] => Testarticle
>         [price] => 15
>         [product_type] => simple
>         [quote_id] => 287
>     )
> ```

the price should be 11 as in the post, but the API response the prie of 15

Comment: want You to  post custom  price  which you have sent from  post  parameters

Answer (score 0):

**`/V1/carts/{cartId}/items`** is an endpoint for **GET** request.
Try with the following endpoint instead:

For **POST:**

```
/V1/carts/{quoteId}/items
/V1/carts/mine/items
```

For **PUT**

```
/V1/carts/{cartId}/items/{itemId}  
/V1/carts/mine/items/{itemId}
```

Comment: quoteId and cartId are still the same?
the response of POST V1/customers/631/carts is the id to which i post the items

Comment: @Jan I'm not really sure but I think is the same. The id from `V1/customers/631/carts` is the quoteId you use to POST items to cart using `/V1/carts/{quoteId}/items` endpoint and then from there, you get the cart id from response which you use to update the cart items using `/V1/carts/{cartId}/items/{itemId}` endpoint

Comment: yes i think im right but...i send to the endpoint this json:
`{
  "cartItem": {
    "item_id": 189,
    "quoteId":289,  
    "price": 89,
     "qty":1
  }
}` and get this response: `{
  "cartItem": {
    "item_id": 189,
    "quoteId":289,  
    "price": 89,
     "qty":1
  }
}`   so the price will not accept